# How to use multiget with memcache in PHP

Tags: php, caching, memcached

Just like the title, how would a multiget from memcache look like?

Is this the correct way of utilizing multiget? :

```
$memcache_obj = new Memcache;
$memcache_obj->connect('memcache_host', 11211);
$var = $memcache_obj->get(Array('some_key', 'second_key'));
```

Thanks

UPDATE: anyone looking to do the same, check out this addition as well: http://www.craigiam.com/blog/19/memcached-multiget-using-php-pecl-memcache-class

Big thanks to Pascal_Martin for solving the issue!

Comment: Yes.  That is the correct way of utilizing multiget.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Considering that [**Memcache::get**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.memcache-get.php) accepts, as its first parameter, either one key, or an array of keys, I'd say it is ;-)

Quoting :

> You can pass array of keys to
> `Memcache::get()`  to get array of
> values.  
> The result array will
> contain only found key-value pairs.